# How to change call test parameters in ALM?

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center, test-plan

I have created a test Templates it has just one step and I have used 3 parameters A,B,C. I have to run this script for 10 cases and every time A and B will remain the same but C will Change.

One thing i can do is every time just pull the test cases and add those parameters (A,B,C) to it and my scripts will get prepared. But here as A and B are constant cant i copy the test case and just modify the Single Parameter C for the second test case. Please suggest.

I cannot create a template with just parameter C as there are different scenarios where A and B will also be getting changed. So i have to use only one template.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Moshin Hilal Kondkari:

from your query I have not understood if you are using a sort of automation (REST API /VXAPI) or if the GUI (graphical interface).

Anyway coming to a point below some solutions:

1)If you are using a REST-API/VXAPI, then a suitable way will be to create a proper xml/json file format and send it to the server back.
Since you are creating a new test-cases, no need to pull a previous test-case, but just use again the same xml file (if you have one) with the correct parameter modified (param-C). Of course some of the default value will have to be adapted and for instance the name cannot be the same.

I am using REST API and a module called requests from Python to automate the whole and it is working really reliable already with older version of QC ALM.

2) If you want to have something like in a version control, then please check the "checkout option" if it is enabled in your Server. This will help you in case you want to use always same Test-Case-Name.

In QC you can checkout a file, make some adaptation of param-X and check in again. The QC ALM will remember the history and you will not loose any info. In this case you should be a bit familiar with version-control system like svn or git.

3) In case you are using the GUI, then again for the version control system have a look at the options coming onto the bar:
you can enable the versioning, approve one Test case as [1.0]Test Case Name and create a complete copy of your test case (even the requirements) and then modify param-X for that copy.

4) Play completely manually and create new Test-case with param-A-B-C.

Hope this clarify your query! I wish you a nice day!